# How to push array into another non empty array in typescript? join if needed

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, join, push

this array contains atleast 10 objects

```
 array: any[] = [];
```

When a function is called, an array is expected to contain both existing and new objects from "item".

```
 function () {
    var timeline = this.service.fetchservice(10)
    .map((result : Response) => result.json())
    .subscribe(item=> {
          this.array.push(item);
        });
    }
```

error in console

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.array.push is not a function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

something like:

```
 this.results = this.results.concat(data.results);
```

Comment: Tried it but got this error.

_this.results.concat is not a function

Comment: then you didn't define your this.array

Comment: Concat worked. Thanks Carsten.
My problem was that, {} covering this.array instead []. I tried .push and it now worked too.

Answer (score -2):

When using `function()`, this takes on the context of the function itself. You should use Typescript class methods, such as:

```
export class TestApp {

   someMethod(): void {
      // does something 
  }
}
```

Comment: : void didn't bring up any error but couldn't tell the benefit. Could u explain ?